# iOS Swift 2.0 Done Button

Tags: ios, keyboard, swift2

I'm trying to add a Done button to a keyboard.  The code below used to work:

```
func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
{
    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 50))
    //doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: Selector("doneButtonAction"))

    var items: [UIBarButtonItem]?
    items?.append(flexSpace)
    items?.append(done)

    doneToolbar.items = items
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
    commentsField.inputAccessoryView=doneToolbar
}
```

It puts the toolbar above the keyboard but there is no done button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the line

```
var items: [UIBarButtonItem]?
```

Your array of `UIBarButtonItem` is never initialized. Replace this line with

```
var items: [UIBarButtonItem]? = [UIBarButtonItem]()
```